# Rails => concatenate integer and string inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Is it possible to concatenate an integer and a string inside a model? Something like this:

```
percent = 50
string = (percent + "%")
```

Trying this I am getting a Type Error:

> TypeError (String can't be coerced into Fixnum):
>     app/models/game.rb:124:in `+'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by different ways:

```
string = "#{number}%" # or number.to_s + "%"
=> "50%"
```

Or by using [`number_to_percentage`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_percentage) Rails helper:

```
string = number_to_percentage(number)
```

Comment: number_to_percentage doesn't seem to work: NoMethodError (undefined method `number_to_percentage' for #<Game:0x007fcfb72bd598>):

Comment: @Lars, see my answer: only in views, since it is a helper. Or include helpers: `include ActionView::Helpers` in models.

Comment: Ok. I missed this hint. string = "#{number}%" works in my model

Answer (score 1):

```
percent = 50
percentstring = percent.to_s
string = percentstring + "%"
```

.to_s = to string

Comment: According [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation) better use string interpolation instead of concatenation.

Comment: he asked for concatenation :P